# "Социально терпимый" или "социально-терпимый"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно: "социально терпимый" или "социально-терпимый"?

Answer (score 1):

Пишется в два слова, но если это используется как специальный термин в какой-то узкой научной области, то можно написать через дефис, так как *"социальный"* и *"терпимый"* не образуют словосочетания.

Answer (score 0):

Без дефиса точно. Так же как "общественно полезный" и др.

Comment: Согласна. Но вот в качестве обоснования "общественно полезный" приводить бы поостереглась. Здесь много сложных моментов. По сути затрагиваете вопросы: 1. Как отличить словосочетание от сложного прилагательного (есть , например, труд общественно-полезный, а есть общественно полезный) 2. Как пишутся сложные прилагательные. Оба вопроса очень неоднозначны.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, я рассуждала так: терпимый (к кому?чему?) социуму, обществу, полезный (для кого?чего?)общества. На мой взгляд, эти выражения сходны по структуре.
Насчёт "общественно полезный": уверена, что всегда раздельно. Ищу дефисное - не нахожу. Помогите!

Comment: Что касается дефисного написания, вот у Розенталя:  Различаются сложные прилагательные, образующие одно слово, и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о (-е) и прилагательного или причастия (с раздельным написанием)...
общественно-исторические законы (бесспорно-Е.К.)– общественно опасные элементы (опасные для кого?);
промышленно-транспортный отдел – промышленно развитая страна (развитая в каком отношении?).
Наречие может указывать также на степень признака, выраженного прилагательным или причастием, например: максимально сжатые сроки, невозмутимо бесстрашный вид, умеренно теплый климат.

Comment: Труд может быть общественный в значении "неиндивидуальный". Например, предмет в школе раньше так и назывался: общественно-  полезный труд.

Comment: Ушаков объясняет слово общественный:  "4. Не индивидуальный, предназначенный для всех, для общего пользования. Весь холм занят храмами и общественными зданиями. Чернышевский". Тут другой нюанс. 
Предмет в школе должен был называться "Общественно полезный труд". Не индивидуальный труд значит общий, совместный труд. Совместный общественно полезный труд.

Comment: Про значение названия школьного предмета можно спорить, боюсь, здесь не место. Однако он все-таки писался через дефис. Дефисное написание было зафиксировано и словарями.Причем безотносительно к труду.Согласна, что сейчас словари дают и раздельное написание. На мой взгляд, вопрос до конца не решен. И в рамках форума его не решить. Тем более в рамках данного вопроса. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Общественно  полезный всегда (и предмет школьный в том числе) писалось раздельно. И в ученических дневниках в 60-70-е годы была графа под этим названием (с раздельным написанием).

Comment: Орфографический словарь русского языка: АН СССР. Институт русского языка. Под редакцией Бархударова. 1994 год. 26-е стереотипное издание. С.323.

Comment: Как Вы можете быть так категоричны? Да по-разному писалось. И даже вот так: (Краткий политологический толковый словарь)
Труд - процесс, совершающийся между человеком и природой, работа по ее преобразованию, имеющая целью создание потребительской стоимости. 
Термином "общественно-полезный труд" традиционно называется ОБЩЕСТВЕННО ПОЛЕЗНАЯ деятельность, ведущая к укреплению общества. Деятельность, наносящая обществу или другим людям ущерб, ведущая к отчуждению собственности, ослаблению или разрушению общества ОБЩЕСТВЕННО-ПОЛЕЗНЫМ  трудом не является 
А всего лишь труд на деятельность заменили.:)

Comment: Коллеги, еще раз: я НЕ настаиваю на дефисном написании. Я лишь говорю о том. что и в практике написания, и в весьма уважаемых словарях и справочниках были зафиксированы РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ варианты.

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, за категоричность. Я не права. А вот аналогичный случай: личностно ориентированный.   Встречаются тоже разные написания.